# Binary to Denary Converter in Java

Tags: java, binary, converters

trying to make a converter of binary to denary in java, but I'm not sure whats going wrong, I have a feeling its in my loop, any help would be much appreciated! I am following pseudo code if you would like to see it!

```
System.out.println("Enter a binary number");

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String binaryString = sc.next();

int binaryLength = binaryString.length();

int multiplier = 1;
int denaryValue = 0; 

for(int n = binaryLength; n >= 1; n--){
    int digit = n;
    denaryValue = denaryValue + digit * multiplier;
    multiplier = multiplier * 2;
}
System.out.println("The denary equivalent is " + denaryValue);
```

Comment: you never use binaryString to get the bits

Comment: +1. You did a good job asking this question; the question itself is clear and you provided the relevant code, and only the relevant code.

Answer (score 3):

The absolute easiest way is with `Integer.parseInt(String, 2);` (in your case: `Integer.parseInt(binaryString, 2);`).

However, if you really want to run the loop:

```
for(int n = binaryLength; n >= 1; n--){
    int digit = binaryString.charAt(n - 1) - '0';
    denaryValue = denaryValue + digit * multiplier;
    multiplier = multiplier * 2;
}
```

Personally, I'd do this if I really wanted to reinvent the wheel:

```
if (!binaryString.matches("[01]+")) {
    //here we know that there is a character that is not a 0 or a 1
    //or that the string is empty
}
for(char c : binaryString.toCharArray()) {
    denaryValue += c - '0';
    denaryValue <<= 1; //binary left shift; multiply by 2
}
denaryValue >>= 1; //binary right shift; divide by 2
```

Comment: -1.  Your second fragment doesn't give the right answer.  Two upvoters, please explain.

Comment: @DavidWallace Hey, sometimes I make mistakes. Calm down.

Comment: Oh, I have no objection to people posting answers with mistakes in them.  That is what downvotes are for.  And, in fact, I frequently post answers with mistakes in, myself.  What I object to is people who upvote an answer, without having any idea whether the code in the answer actually works.  I've even seen people upvoting answers that don't compile.  So my beef is not with you.  By the way, despite your fix, this still doesn't work correctly - I tried `binaryString = "11001"`, expecting `denaryValue == 25` but got `denaryValue == 50`.

Comment: @DavidWallace Thanks. I have no objection to such downvotes either, but I felt it was harsh to say "Two upvoters, please explain.". That made me feel like you were claiming my answer had nothing right. The `Integer#parseInt(String,int)` method is correct and good form (that was when the first upvoter voted). I agree that the last code-fragment was incorrect, but I feel that it is better to gently explain what was wrong (downvoting if you feel like it)

Comment: OK, but think of it this way.  There are professional programmers who use Stack Overflow as a serious reference. I am one of them. That's kind of the original purpose of Stack Overflow. Such people would like to know that if they have a problem, and they find the problem in the form of a Stack Overflow question, that an answer with many upvotes has been endorsed by other professional programmers, or at least people who are well qualified to endorse an answer.  It's about trust.  I see upvotes and I trust the answer. Therefore, I think it's wrong to upvote any answer that has mistakes in it ...

Comment: because those mistakes are going to end up in someone's production code base.  Anything that I can do to discourage people from upvoting answers with mistakes, I will do.  I'm sorry that you took that as some kind of insult.  Like I said, I didn't intend to have a go at you; rather at the two people who upvoted you.  I don't think they should have done that.

Comment: For what it's worth, you've now provided three answers, wrapped up as one. The first one is the best, and is absolutely worthy of an upvote. The second one (the one you've labelled "better") now works correctly, but the fact that you struggled a little to make it work indicates that it's a bit less intuitive than the first, and therefore is not as good. Your third answer (labelled "even better") doesn't quite do what you think it does - that regular expression isn't really right; and it makes the whole answer worth a downvote. If you remove the third answer, my -1 will become +1.

Comment: @DavidWallace Sorry, I changed my mind halfway through writing the regular expression; now it works correctly. I will edit as you recommend. Also, I did not take offense at the downvote; I also agree with you, but I did feel insulted. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

The digit value was wrong:

```
int digit = binaryString.charAt(n - 1) - '0';
```