# How do you split a integer by a digits and put into a list in java?

Tags: java

How would I split a binary number up by each individual digit and then put it into a java list back to front.

For example:
Binary Number:

```
01111101
```

After it is split up it would look like

```
int[] binary = {0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1}
```

After it the array is flipped it would look like

```
int[] binaryFlipped={1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0}
```

I am doing this so that I can convert a binary number into a denary number in java.
So i would take the flipped list the for each binary digit work out it's denary value. This is an example of ruffle how i would do it. (Note: lengthOfList is not the write method but is just there for an example of how it would work)

```
For(x=0;lengthOflist(binary);x++){
    sum=binary[x]*pow(2,x)+sum;
    }
System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: Did you try using Integer.parseInt("01111101", 2); ?

Comment: What is your binary number originally? A string? (And of course david is right, but I assume that your job is to do it yourself *g*)

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz His title states that he's using an Integer.

Comment: I will look at the other stack overflow question and if it is a duplicate I will close it myself. Otherwise I will tell you the difference. Please keep open in the mean time.

Comment: have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21416637/binary-to-denary-converter-in-java)

Comment: Yes sure. (But this post has been banned because it similar to another post however I wont the array to be flipped as well.

Comment: @Jishnu Prathap So an example: binary:0101 array: int[] binary={0,1,0,1} arrayFlipped: binary={1,0,1,0}

Comment: The binary number in denary would be 5

Comment: all of the data is saved as integer. As shown in the example (maybe i didn't make that clear).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your input is an `int` and not a `String`:

```
    int number = 2;
    int[] binaryFlipped = new int[8];
    for (int i = 0; i < binaryFlipped.length; i++) {
        binaryFlipped[i] = number % 2;
        number = number >> 1;
    }
```

Comment: which variable is the binary number?

Comment: I used `int[8]` because your example had 8 bits but an int precision in Java is 32 bits.

Comment: There is no interim binary number in this implementation

Comment: I get that. But which variable would I output to get the flipped binary number

Comment: I suppose it is `binaryFlipped` since that is the name you used in your code :)

Comment: You could use `number & 1` instead of `number % 2`

Comment: Sorry it did sound stupid. But i outputed binaryFlipped using. System.out.println(binaryFlipped); and i got this: [I@659e0bfd

Comment: @matt: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-a-java-array :). What you see there is the default result of the `toString` method.

Comment: If you need the denary representation of `binaryFlipped`, then I am leaving it to you as an exercise. Your question contains something that seems OK to me, but you could also try something with the binary operator `<<`.

Comment: No I will to the converting bit by myself. However I just need to check the value of the binaryflipprd before moving on and currently that is not the expected output

Comment: Just add `System.out.print(binaryFlipped[i] + " ");` at the end of the `for` loop.